# Can't receive msgs published with rabbitmq

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

i set up a small nodejs project with express. created a folder in the root called "connectors" in which i have two files: pulisher.js and consumer.js. and in routes folder in index.js i call an endpoint that publishes a msg and calls the consumer to consume it. Here is the code of publisher and consumer and index

Publisher.js

```
var config = require('../config');
var open = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://'+ config.rabbitmq.url);
var queue = 'hello'
var msg = 'hello world!'
module.exports = open.then(function(conn) {
        return conn.createChannel();
}).then(function(ch) {
         return ch.assertQueue(queue,{durable:false})
                .then(function(ok) {
                        const r =  ch.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(msg));
                        console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
                        return r
        });
}).catch(console.warn);
```

Consumer.js

```
var config = require('../config');
var open = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://'+ config.rabbitmq.url);
var queue = 'hello'
module.exports = open.then(function(conn) {
return conn.createChannel();
}).then(function(ch) {
        return ch.assertQueue(queue, {durable: false})
                .then(function(ok) {
                        console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", queue);
                        return ch.consume(queue, function(msg) {
                         console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
                         ch.ack(msg)
                        }, {
                                noAck: false
                        });
  });
}).catch(console.warn);
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var publisher = require('../connectors/publisher');
var consumer = require('../connectors/consumer');
async function pub(){
        publisher
                .then(res=>{
                        console.log('-----------------------')
                        console.log('publishing now',res)
                }).then(()=>{
                        consumer.
                                then(res=>{
                                        console.log('consuming',res)
                                })
                })


}
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', async(req, res, next) => {
        const result_pub = await pub()
        res.send('ok')
});

module.exports = router;
```

I use postman to call the "/" endpoint , i expect to see the msg fired by console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString()); 
but it doesn't show, it is like it's not consuming the msg ,
And when i call the endpoint it doesn't even console.log "sent hello world"
This is the output i get :

### GET / 200 11.934 ms - 2

publishing now true
consuming { consumerTag: 'amq.ctag-BsHsykyMrPKvT1nAjmGmBg' }

Thanks for your help !

Comment: If you share this code via a GitHub repo that I can fork, clone, run, and debug, it would be much easier to help out.

Comment: @LukeBakken , here is a link for the code, (i am sorry it is not in github repo) Thank you : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iOiZsUmddpAeXgRdwurx0uI-imsWCviO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @LukeBakken I believe i am doing sth wrong with the promises ... i dnt know ...

Comment: Well, I definitely have no idea how to code with promises. Here's some non-working code showing what I was trying to do - https://github.com/lukebakken/stackoverflow-55949567-1466825. Good luck!